# How to override a function that returns a list of generic objects that extend a base class with a specific object

Tags: c#, generics, overriding

I have a base class (Company) and want to derive a few classes (say CompanyA, CompanyB etc) from it.

This base class has an abstract method so that all derived classes have to override and implement it.

The catch is that this abstract method should be able return a list of any object that is derived from a given class (say CustomerContact).

I tried defining this method in the base class as follows:

```
public class Company
{
    ...
    public abstract List<T> getContacts<T>() where T : CustomerContact;
}
```

This give no compilation error. I try to override this method as follows in the derived class:

```
public class CompanyA : Company
{
    ...
    public override List<T> getContacts<T>()
    {
        return _contacts;
    }
}
```

Here _contacts is a List of class "CompanyAContact" where this class is derived from "CustomerContact".

However, I cannot override the method like this. The error I get is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CompanyAContact>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method in the derived class is defined as a generic but returning a concrete list of `CompanyAContact` - what would happen if you called the method like this for example?:

```
CompanyA companyA = new CompanyA();
//we can't do this as the method returns List<CompanyAContact>
//but we would be asking it for List<CompanyBContact>
companyA.getContacts<CompanyBContact>();
```

As that wouldn't make any sense you receive the error that you can't convert from `List<CompanyAContact>` to `List<T>`. You can't return a `List<CompanyAContact>` when the method is defined in such a way that it could return *any* `CompanyContact`.

One solution would be to make the base `Company` class *itself* generic and define the `CompanyContact` type when you inherit the `Company`:

```
abstract class BaseCompany<T> where T : CustomerContact
{
    //When we inherit from BaseCompany we can define T
    public abstract List<T> getContacts();
}

//define T in this case as CompanyACustomerContact
class CompanyA : BaseCompany<CompanyACustomerContact> 
{
    public override List<CompanyACustomerContact> getContacts() 
    {
        return new List<CompanyACustomerContact>();
    }
}    

//define T in this case as CompanyBCustomerContact
class CompanyB : BaseCompany<CompanyBCustomerContact>
{
    public override List<CompanyBCustomerContact> getContacts()
    {
        return new List<CompanyBCustomerContact>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Visual Studio in front of me to check, but I suspect you need to add the type constraint here also, to show that this method is compatible with the abstract method:

```
public class CompanyA : Company
{
    ...
    public override List<T> getContacts<T>() where T : CustomerContact;
    {
        return _contacts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return list of CustomerContact class and then derive specific classes from it,  like mobile,  email...

Answer (score 0):

Try making the Base Class generic instead:

```
public class CustomerContact
{
    // ...
}
public class CompanyAContact : CustomerContact
{
    // ...
}

public abstract class Company<T> where T : CustomerContact
{
    // ...
    public abstract List<T> GetContacts();
}
public class CompanyA : Company<CompanyAContact>
{
    private List<CompanyAContact> _contacts; 
    // ...
    public override List<CompanyAContact> GetContacts()
    {
        return _contacts;
    }
}
```